# How to ask users to confirm an item as True Positive or False Positive

Tags: tables, dashboard, confirmation, classification, machine-learning

I have an ML system which classifies a series of objects. These objects have a possible status `X` assigned by the system.

This information is displayed on a dashboard table to users.

An example output is below:

| Object | Is X? |
| --- | --- |
| A | X |
| B | X |
| C |  |
| D | X |
| E |  |

**I need users to confirm whether the classification for each object is correct (True Positive) or not (False Positive), but its not mandatory.**

What would be a suitable design solution for this? They should ideally be able to do this confirmation on the table itself.

Answer (score 1):

If verifications in your system are expected to produce as many false positives as true positives, a three-state selector would be appropriate (like the Holly's Coffee example in another answer):

Unknown (Default state) | Correct | Incorrect

If false positives are an *exception* and are usually rare, a better pattern would be a flag. Since verifying items is optional, perhaps there is simply a "Mark as invalid" option somewhere in the row actions. Invalid/false positive rows can then be treated differently - red text, moved to another table, different status, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on who the user is and what his tasks are. Is it part of their job or is it mandatory for them to do this?

Is it optional?

I have two suggestions. One would immerse users and create more focus on this task if it is an important task :

[image]

The other version would be to add one extra column called "Your Input"

[image]